# CXF : org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: wrong number of arguments while invoking

Tags: java, apache, web-services, cxf, cxf-codegen-plugin

I'm implementing a simple client using apache cxf and the codegen maven plugin (both release 3.1.11).

Here is my sample wsdl:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="urn:webServiceTest" xmlns:s0="urn:webServiceTest" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <wsdl:types>
  <xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:webServiceTest">
   <xsd:element name="OpenTk" type="s0:InputMapping1"/>
   <xsd:complexType name="InputMapping1">
    <xsd:sequence>
     <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="ID_NOTIFICA" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="ID_MESSAGGIO" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="DATA_ID_NOTIFICA" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
     <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="DATA_ID_MESSAGGIO" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
     <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="ID_RISORSA" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:element name="APERTURATKResponse" type="s0:OutputMapping1"/>
   <xsd:complexType name="OutputMapping1">
    <xsd:sequence>
     <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="CODICE" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="DESCRIZIONE" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="NOTE" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>

   <xsd:element name="AuthenticationInfo" type="s0:AuthenticationInfo"/>
   <xsd:complexType name="AuthenticationInfo">
    <xsd:sequence>
     <xsd:element name="userName" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="password" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="authentication" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="locale" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="timeZone" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:schema>
 </wsdl:types>
   <wsdl:message name="OpenTkSoapOut">
      <wsdl:part element="s0:APERTURATKResponse" name="parameters">
      </wsdl:part>
   </wsdl:message>
   <wsdl:message name="OpenTkSoapIn">
      <wsdl:part element="s0:OpenTk" name="parameters">
      </wsdl:part>
   </wsdl:message>
   <wsdl:message name="ARAuthenticate">
      <wsdl:part element="s0:AuthenticationInfo" name="parameters">
      </wsdl:part>
   </wsdl:message>
   <wsdl:portType name="New_Port_0PortType">
      <wsdl:operation name="OpenTk">
         <wsdl:input message="s0:OpenTkSoapIn">
       </wsdl:input>
         <wsdl:output message="s0:OpenTkSoapOut">
       </wsdl:output>
      </wsdl:operation>
   </wsdl:portType>
   <wsdl:binding name="New_Port_0SoapBinding" type="s0:New_Port_0PortType">
      <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
      <wsdl:operation name="OpenTk">
         <soap:operation soapAction="urn:webServiceTest/OpenTk" style="document"/>
         <wsdl:input>
            <soap:header message="s0:ARAuthenticate" part="parameters" use="literal">
            </soap:header>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:input>
         <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:output>
      </wsdl:operation>
   </wsdl:binding>
   <wsdl:service name="WebServicesFWCFFService">
      <wsdl:port binding="s0:New_Port_0SoapBinding" name="New_Port_0Soap">
         <soap:address location="http://localhost:9090/testService"/>
      </wsdl:port>
   </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

I need to change client endpoint so I decided to use cxf.frontend feature. I created a simple Client and I used the api to set the address property.
Here is the code:

```
QName SERVICE = new QName("urn:webServiceTest", "WebServicesFWCFFService");

URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("testWsdl.wsdl").toURI().toURL();
            NewPort0PortType portType = new WebServicesFWCFFService(url, SERVICE).getNewPort0Soap();
            Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(portType);
            client.getRequestContext().put(Message.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS,address);
```

Then inside my unit tests I try to invoke the service (the service created by codegen plugin) doing:

```
ClientTest client = new ClientTest();
        Holder<String> code= new Holder<>();
        Holder<String> description= new Holder<>();
        Holder<String> notes= new Holder<>();
        client.portType.openTk("12","",
                null,null,"1",code, description, notes);
        assertNotNull(notes.value);
        assertNotNull(code.value);
```

but I receive a soap fault org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: wrong number of arguments while invoking public void it.test.cxf.impl.New_Port_0SoapImpl.openTk.

I found that the problem seems to be inside org.apache.cxf.jaxws.interceptors.WrapperClassOutInterceptor and in particular when this interceptor create a WrapperHelper class using the method getHelperWrapper. 
Then uses this wrapper to create the object using the ObjectFactory created by codegen plugin (createWrapperObject(objs);). This results in a new InputMappin1 object with all filds null.

Can someone explane me this behaviour and how I can avoid this? Do I need to implement some kind of custom interceptor or I'm missing some configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but here is my 2 cents.

As you said, this seems a bug in cxf. I got the same error exposing a SOAP service with JBoss, using JAX-WS annotations in source code (my approach is contract-last, I start with an annotated java class and let cxf generate the service with its WSDL).

To overcome the problem, I specified the SOAP binding style as DOCUMENT, and parameters style as WRAPPED.
I used JAX WS annotation on the Service class:

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(
        style = SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT, 
        parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.WRAPPED)
public class MySoapService
```

You can read more details about [SOAP bindings here](https://javajee.com/additional-soap-binding-attributes-and-attribute-cominations).
Anyway, this changes the structure of XML messages, but cxf will handle all the details for you.